MOSFET spikes with a load in a transitories voltage protection system



I am taking measurements of a protection system. Internally, it has a configuration like the one attached in the image.
What happens is that when measuring with the oscilloscope probe on the G and D of the MOSFET, I observe very large spikes, something that shouldn’t happen since the system is designed not to exceed certain voltage limits.
The 4.7 Ω load is a wire-wound resistor in an aluminum case. I believe that the switching of the MOSFET, lacking an RC snubber, and the load itself, which may have significant inductance due to the switching frequency, along with the probe using the ground with a crocodile clip, are heavily affecting my measurements.
I have tried not using the ground with the crocodile clip and measuring with a current probe, and I see better results.
Therefore, I think there is some inductance in the load, and the lack of an RC snubber is causing these spikes. Could you help me with some advice to reduce this and measure the signals I’m interested in more stably?
In the scope the blue signal is the Vds, the red one Vgs and the green one the Id.
There is an electrolytic capacitor and a TVS bi-directional diode
There is a bidirectional TVS diode in parallel an electrolytic bypass capacitor.
The D2 diode is at the other end of the location of the capacitor and TVS diode, about 5 cm of wire/trace.
Thank you very much.
The Vds of my NMOS is 150V.
I have added a new schematic design with some additional components. The R1 resistor is a wire-wound resistor that I think could have its own parasitic capacitance and inductance.

What have you measured? -- share oscilloscope screenshots. || What is the path length (traces and wiring) back from D2, through Vdd, to the nearest large bypass capacitor (typically electrolytic, or a converter)?

I have edited my post with the information you asked
Thank u

Can you zoom out a bit in your schematic? What does the layout look like? How much inductance do you have in your loop through the MOSFET and load via your Vdd rail?

The vertical scale is 89.6V, are you sure? The Si7336ADP is rated only 30V.

It’s a basic schematic with a regulator that powers the driver, which controls the MOSFET based on whether we have a voltage that needs to be absorbed.
From the tests I've done and the information I've gathered, the problem seems to be a small inductance at the D of the MOSFET that, due to the switching frequency, increases the spike.

I’m not sure if not having an RC snubber on the MOSFET is significantly affecting this. I thought that using D2 as a flyback diode would reduce this significantly. However, as seen in the measurements, spikes on the order of 90V are being generated, which could affect the MOSFET.
I’m not sure what you mean by the inductance present. If you are referring to the circuit, I don’t have any physical inductor. The connection between the capacitor and the diode is a copper trace.

Sorry but the components were not available and i used some of them listed in LTspice

You mention a wirewound resistor. Wirewounds, by virtue of their construction, inherently have pretty high parasitic inductance--even ones with non-inductive windings (which are wound both clockwise and counterclockwise) tend to have more parasitic inductance than other types of resistor. So, yes, you do have a physical inductor.

I will try desoldering and replacing it with another type of impedance that doesn’t have as much parasitic inductance and see if the measurements are more in line with the simulations I’m getting, since those spikes are not of the same magnitude, which I imagine is due to the inductance of the PCB layout, etc.

Well, you don't show a complete schematic, clear description thereof, or part numbers, but the waveform can be described roughly as the transient response of an RLCD network:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
with response,

Note I'm (ab)using the BJT as a rectifier because CircuitLab doesn't model diodes correctly (in particular, TT is ignored; but not for the BJT).
The component values are very rough, as the prompt turn-off transient is longer than the real thing; but just as well, CircuitLab is awful at simulating widely different time constants.  Probably C1 is much smaller, and much more capacitance belongs to D2/Q1.
In particular, the ringdown amplitude is not possible with just a diode as shown; this aspect of the waveform invalidates your schematic.  Clarity of communication is important in technical subjects!
In any case, the equivalent circuit may help you understand what aspects of the circuit are important to pay attention to, in particular that lead/trace/wire length matters, particularly when dI/dt is high.

You are right
Sorry because i am not able to provide much info of schematics
I have tested in LTSpice some diferent circuits with Inductances in the load RL and the Flyback DIode works really well so i will try to test a different device to verify if the problem is there

I dont know if the edit i have done could help u more
